# In Redux Toolkit, how to call a reducer function from the inside of the other

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, redux-toolkit

Here is my code:

```
// index.tsx
<button id="start_stop" onClick={() => dispatch(toggleSwitch({ dispatch }))}>
  {active ? "Pause" : "Start"}
</button>

// timerSlice.ts
// ...
const timerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "timer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleSwitch: (state, action) => {
      const { dispatch } = action.payload;
      if (state.intervalId) {
        clearInterval(state.intervalId);
        return {
          ...state,
          intervalId: null,
          active: false,
        };
      } else {
        // I NEED HELP WITH THIS PART
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          if (state.timer === 0) {
            const audio = document.getElementById("beep") as HTMLAudioElement;
            playAudio(audio);
            // 1. How to call to sibling reducer function
            // 2. Is it correct to use dispatch
            dispatch(timerSlice.actions.toggleStatus());
            dispatch(timerSlice.actions.recalculateTimer());
            return;
          }
          dispatch(timerSlice.actions.decreaseTimer());
        }, 1000);
        return {
          ...state,
          active: true,
          intervalId,
        };
      }
    },
    decreaseBreak: (state, action) => {
      const { dispatch } = action.payload;
      if (state.active || state.break <= 1) return;
      state.break = state.break - 1;
      if (state.status === "BREAK") {
        // 3. How can I call a common-use reducer from another, like nested functions 
        dispatch(timerSlice.actions.recalculateTimer());
      }
    },
    // ...
  }  
});
```

This code gives me the following error on the console:
**Uncaught Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store.**

I tried not to call a reducer from the other as possible, but it had a lot of repeated code and the worst, I should call to another reducer func inside the setInterval callback func anyway. then I tried to convert common-use reducer functions to pure functions:

```
const toggleStatus = (state: ITimer): ITimer => {
  return {
    ...state,
    status: state.status === "SESSION" ? "BREAK" : "SESSION",
  };
};

const recalculateTimer = (state: ITimer): ITimer => {
  return {
    ...state,
    timer: state[state.status.toLowerCase() as "session" | "break"] * 60,
  };
};

toggleSwitch: (state) => {
      if (state.intervalId) {
        // ...
      } else {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          if (state.timer === 0) {
            const audio = document.getElementById("beep") as HTMLAudioElement;
            playAudio(audio);
            // HERE IS THE NEW CODE
            const toggledStatusState = toggleStatus(state);
            const recalculatedTimerState = recalculateTimer(toggledStatusState);
            return recalculatedTimerState;
          }
          state.timer = state.timer - 1;
        }, 1000);
        return {
          ...state,
          active: true,
          intervalId,
        };
      }
    },
```

this also gives me an Error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
**

Comment: Redux reducer functions are ***pure***, synchronous functions, so they ***can not*** initiate timers/intervals/network requests/etc, they should simply compute the next state given the current state and an action. Move all that timer logic into the UI and use a `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect. Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @DrewReese I completely forgot about this. Thank you so much for your recommendation. I just wanted to know if it is possible to reuse common reducer function from the other reducer function inside the slice, for example **setRectangleHeight** and **setRectangleWidth**, each funcs should call to **recalculatePerimeter** func inside

Comment: You can create and use common utility functions if they are also pure functions.